# Optimizing ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, optimization, query-optimization

We have a number of machines which record data into a database at sporadic intervals.  For each record, I'd like to obtain the time period between *this* recording and the *previous* recording.

I can do this using ROW_NUMBER as follows:

```
WITH TempTable AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Machine_ID ORDER BY Date_Time) AS Ordering
    FROM dbo.DataTable
)

SELECT [Current].*, Previous.Date_Time AS PreviousDateTime
FROM TempTable AS [Current]
INNER JOIN TempTable AS Previous 
    ON [Current].Machine_ID = Previous.Machine_ID
    AND Previous.Ordering = [Current].Ordering + 1
```

The problem is, it goes *really* slow (several minutes on a table with about 10k entries) - I tried creating separate indicies on Machine_ID and Date_Time, and a single joined-index, but nothing helps.

Is there anyway to rewrite this query to go faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How does it compare to this version?:

```
SELECT x.*
    ,(SELECT MAX(Date_Time)
      FROM dbo.DataTable
      WHERE Machine_ID = x.Machine_ID
          AND Date_Time < x.Date_Time
    ) AS PreviousDateTime
FROM dbo.DataTable AS x
```

Or this version?:

```
SELECT x.*
    ,triang_join.PreviousDateTime
FROM dbo.DataTable AS x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.Machine_ID, l.Date_Time, MAX(r.Date_Time) AS PreviousDateTime
    FROM dbo.DataTable AS l
    LEFT JOIN dbo.DataTable AS r
    ON l.Machine_ID = r.Machine_ID
        AND l.Date_Time > r.Date_Time
    GROUP BY l.Machine_ID, l.Date_Time
) AS triang_join
ON triang_join.Machine_ID = x.Machine_ID
    AND triang_join.Date_Time = x.Date_Time
```

Both would perform best with an index on Machine_ID, Date_Time and for correct results, I'm assuming that this is unique.

You haven't mentioned what is hidden away in * and that can sometimes means a lot since a Machine_ID, Date_Time index will not generally be covering and if you have a lot of columns there or they have a lot of data, ...

Comment: The second query finishes in seconds rather than minutes, but the first query executes faster than I can time it.  Perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The given ROW_NUMBER() partition and order require an index on `(Machine_ID, Date_Time)` to satisfy in one pass:

```
CREATE INDEX idxMachineIDDateTime ON DataTable (Machine_ID, Date_Time);
```

Separate indexes on Machine_ID and Date_Time will help little, if any.

Comment: As I said, I created that index as well, and it did not improve the query performance at all.

Comment: That is because your * triggers the index tipping point. Restrict it to only the columns needed and use include the make the non-clustered index covering. If too many columns are needed, then it has to be changed to a clustered index, with all the consequences.

Comment: You seem to be correct, removing the * decreases the time of the query to just a few seconds.  I can't envision why this would happen - could you provide any links as to what an *index tipping point* is?

Comment: Well now you know one of the reasons why select * should not be in a production query. Plus you have joins so you were returning unnecessary columns by definition.

Comment: +1 Even though this index may not have helped asker's scenario due to query structure, it does in general improve OVER clause performance.

Comment: Also, I make sure the second column in the index matches ASC/DESC based on the ORDER BY in the OVER clause.  So index would have been ` (Machine_ID, Date_Time desc)` if `OVER(... ORDER BY Date_Time desc)`.  Not sure if it is important, but I do this so it matches the sort in the actual query plan.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of rows in dbo.DataTable is large then it is likely that you are experiencing the issue due to the CTE self joining onto itself.  There is a blog post explaining the issue in some detail [here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/05/17/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-performance-sucks-1-cte-self-join-cte-sub-query-inline-expansion.aspx)

Occasionally in such cases I have resorted to creating a temporary table to insert the result of the CTE query into and then doing the joins against that temporary table (although this has usually been for cases where a large number of joins against the temp table are required - in the case of a single join the performance difference will be less noticable)

Comment: I second this approach.  CTEs are simply inline rewrites.  Just like repeating your own code and self-joining, there is nothing to guarantee that the optimizer will spool it into a temporary table.  If you put things in your own table, you can choose indexes and/or avoid double work.  Having said that, I do use CTEs where code maintenance is important and where the schema is liable to change very quickly (or in views, like this case).

Answer (score 2):

I have had some strange performance problems using CTEs in SQL Server 2005.  In many cases, replacing the CTE with a real temp table solved the problem.

I would try this before going any further with using a CTE.

I never found any explanation for the performance problems I've seen, and really didn't have any time to dig into the root causes.  However I always suspected that the engine couldn't optimize the CTE in the same way that it can optimize a temp table (which can be indexed if more optimization is needed).

**Update**

After your comment that this is a view, I would first test the query with a temp table to see if that performs better.

If it does, and using a stored proc is not an option, you might consider making the current CTE into an indexed/materialized view.  You will want to read up on the subject before going down this road, as whether this is a good idea depends on a lot of factors, not the least of which is how often the data is updated.

Comment: How would I do that?  Would I need to replace the view with an Sproc (since views can't have variables)?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear it was a view from your question.  See the update to my answer (will follow in a few minutes).

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a trigger to store the last timestamp an subtract each time to get the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is historical data, and not always added in order.

Answer (score 0):

If you require this data often, rather than calculate it each time you pull the data, why not add a column and calculate/populate it whenever row is added?

(Remus' compound index will make the query fast; running it only once should make it faster still.)