# In Db2 how to calculate difference of adjacent rows

Tags: sql, db2

I want to calculate the range as row1-row2, need help in db2 query to get the range column

```
name,age,range   
a,40,0     
b,20,20  
c,7,13  
d,5,2  
e,1,4
```

Range column calculation

```
first value is 0  
(40-20)  
(20-7)  
(7-5)  
(5-1)
```

Comment: See also this question: [Optimizing ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960104/optimizing-row-number-in-sql-server) for various other ways to achieve the same results.

Comment: @ypercube: I don't think that post is relevant here as that deals with joining the result sets using the value of a windowing function. And besides: the performance is very implementation specific.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I agree the performance is implementation specific. Without the `lag()` function though, you do need a self-join using the `Row_Number()` windowing function (or some other way to self join).

Comment: @ypercube: I agree. But DB2 does have the `lag()` function :)

Comment: I agree, this is the best way, for versions that have the function.

Comment: @Raj: why did you change the example data? Now your question is completely unclear. And please fix the formatting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       age,
       (lag(age, 1, age) over (order by age desc)) - age as agediff
FROM your_table
ORDER BY age desc
```